# In Java: create unique random filename in a directory

Tags: java, random, filenames

How do I create a random unique filename in a directory (of my choice)?

***Note:*** I don’t want this file in the system temp path but rather in the directory I specify

Comment: And did you look in the File class, perhaps at a method named createTempFile?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I did, and then I ended up here because I did not find any method in the `File` class that does that; certainly not `createTempFile`; that would be OK if I wanted to create the file, which is not what this question asks, regardless of whether the OP wants that or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`File.createTempFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) allows you to specify a directory so:

```
File uniqueFile = File.createTempFile("post", ".html", new File("/var/www/doc"));
```

Answer (score -8):

You want the `File.createTempFile(String, String, File)` overload.

Which you would have seen immediately had you bothered to look at the documentation.